# Lotus Notes Application Opening Message

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Where can I find the editing of the pop-up message when opening the database?

I tried looking for it all over the designer and properties.

Please help, maybe I just missed it.
[image]
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Go to the application properties and look at the tab with the rocket ship.  There's a drop-down labelled "When opened in the Notes client ... " with a number of choices, for example "Open a designated frameset" or "Open the 'About application' document"  That should tell you where to look.

Comment: Hi Duston, thank for you answer, this what my properties look like: `When opened in the Notes client: Open designated Frameset | Name: Main`. So does it mean I can edit on designer under `Framesets: Main` ?

Comment: Hi Duston, found it on Script Libraries, Thanks!